# IBM Quantum Computing Raw I Q data from ADC

Tags: qiskit

Does anybody know if I can acquire raw I and Q data directly from ADC using Qiskit?
I want to experiment with frequency-multiplexed readout to make my own state discriminators

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In [OpenPulse](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1809.03452.pdf), the measurement output level 1 returns the IQ values (see section 5.4.2). You can get that level in Qiskit using the parameter [`meas_level` of `execute`](https://qiskit.org/documentation/tutorials/circuits_advanced/08_gathering_system_information.html) (assuming that's supported by your backend). The [`qiskit-experiments` blogpost on the topic](https://medium.com/qiskit/visualizing-results-in-qiskit-experiments-is-now-easier-than-ever-4edd1df3a1f5) can be a good tutorial for this.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: happy to help, considering accepting the answer if that covers your question.